# Opacity or Page Background is showing on half page on Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a pop up on one of my project.

## CSS Code

```
<style type="text/css">
    #modalPage
    {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
      z-index: 999;
    }
    .modalContainer
    {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    </style>
```

## Content CSS

```
.modal
    {
      background-color: #6f9255;
      position: relative;
      top: -300px;
      left: -305px;
      z-index: 1000;
      width: 600px;
      overflow:auto;

    }
```

## JAVASCRIPT Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById('modalPage').style.display = "block";

}

function hideModal()
    {
      document.getElementById('modalPage').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

## HTML Code

```
<div id="modalPage">
      <div class="modalContainer">
        <div class="modal"> </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that, it is fine but the opacity or page background which I putting on it, it is displaying on half page, not on full page.
Displaying by this code. `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);`
Please tell me, where is the problem.

**I can't keep the position fixed, because my pop up is longer then original page size and it is coming with scroll and cross the footer link too.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not related with an opacity issue. You say that your .modalContainer is 100% width and height but you start it at 50% top left. So the whole thing is 150% width and height, while #modalPage is only 100% width and height.

If you know the exact width and height of your container I suggest you to simply modify your css to center propertly the container. For example:

```
.modalContainer
    {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      left: 25%;
      top: 25%;
      z-index: 999;
      background-color: red; /*added to see where the container is*/
    }
```

Working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/L2cXP/

If you want a modal longer than the page itself, i suggest a new approach.

We can ignore vertical centering because the modal is longer than the page. We just want that #modalPage has a overflow: auto property so it will show a scrollbar when its contents are longer than it.

Probably you would like to add an overflow: hidden property to the body when the modal shows to block the standard scrollbar of your page.

Check this working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/L2cXP/1/

Comment: You say right. I should insert vertical scroll bar in pop up, by adding overflow: auto; now it is fine. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#modalPage {
    position: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/68Sty/

Comment: Sorry. I can't keep the position fixed, because its length is little bit long.

Comment: er what? What are you tying to achieve?

Comment: dear please review the question one again, cause i have changed little bit the question.

Answer (score 0):

.modalContainer has a "left" of 50%, so starting at halfway is expected. Try something like:

```
.modalContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: dear please review the question one again, cause i have changed little bit the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="modalPage">
    <div class='relative'>
        <div class="modalContainer">
           <div class="modal"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

your css

```
 .relative{
     position:relative;
     zoom:1;
     height:100%; 
     width:100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little CSS magic - and we have simple and nice CSS popups with no javascript positioning! consider this demo:

HTML:

```
<div id="modalPage" class="csspopup-overlay">
    <div class="modalContainer csspopup-popup">
        <div class="csspopup-close" onclick="hideModal()">&times;</div>
        <div class="modal">Some modal content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I define `.csspopup-overlay` and `.csspopup-popup` in CSS as follows:

```
.csspopup-overlay {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        text-align: center;
}
.csspopup-overlay:after, .csspopup-valignfix {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        *zoom: 1;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        content: '';
}
.csspopup-popup {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        *zoom: 1;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 80%;
        padding: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background: #FFF;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 6px;
}
.csspopup-popup > .csspopup-close {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        right: -12px;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        padding: 4px;
        border: 4px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #555;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/acA73/

Note: I extracted these CSS for you from https://github.com/dfsq/cssPopup jQuery plugin.